# Front end post form won't post categories to custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, front-end

Trying to get a front end post form to work with my custom post type. It posting to the post type but the 2 custom taxonomies and the tag field aren't posting/saving.
Here is my CPT.

```
add_action('init', 'portfolio_register'); 
 function portfolio_register() {

$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('User Lists', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('User List', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'list item'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New List'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit List Item'),
    'new_item' => __('New List Item'),
    'view_item' => __('View List Item'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Lists'),
    'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(
'labels' => $labels,
'public' => true, 
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/cutleries.png',
'rewrite' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'hierarchical' => false,
'show_admin_column' => true,
'menu_position' => null,
'taxonomies' => array('post_tag', 'list_type', 'list_state'),
'supports' => array('title',
    'editor',
    'author',
    'custom-fields',
    'comments')
      );

register_post_type( 'user_lists' , $args ); }

register_taxonomy("list_type", array("user_lists"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "List Types", "singular_label" => "List Type", "rewrite" => true, 'show_admin_column' => true,)); 

register_taxonomy("list_state", array("user_lists"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "List State", "singular_label" => "List State", "rewrite" => true, 'show_admin_column' => true,));
```

And here is my form

```
<?php
     //EricHamby.Com
     add_shortcode('feEditor', 'feEDoShortcode');
    add_action('init', 'catch_save_form');

function catch_save_form()
{
 $errors = array();

   if('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post")
{
  // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
if(isset ($_POST['title']))
  $title =  $_POST['title'];
else
  $errors[] = 'Please enter the wine name';

if(isset ($_POST['description']))
  $description = $_POST['description'];
else
  $errors[] = 'Please enter some notes';

$tags = $_POST['post_tags'];

    // ADD THE FORM INPUT TO $new_post ARRAY
       $new_post = array('post_title'      => stripslashes($title),
                  'post_content'    => stripslashes($description),
                  'tags_input'      => stripslashes($tags),
                  'post_status'     => 'publish', // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
                    'post_type'       => 'user_lists', //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
                  'tax_input'    => array(
                    'list_type'  => $_POST['list_type'],
                    'list_state' => $_POST['list_state'],
       )
   );

  //SAVE THE POST
    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

  //REDIRECT TO THE NEW POST ON SAVE
  $link = get_permalink( $pid );
 $_POST['form_errors'] = $errors;
 wp_redirect( $link );
 die(); 
    } // END THE IF STATEMENT
      }

   //WHERE ALL THE MAGIC HAPPENS
     function feEDoShortcode()
   {
    if(isset($_POST['form_errors']) && !empty($_POST['form_errors']))
     foreach($_POST['form_errors'] as $e)
      echo '<p class="form_error">ERROR: '.$e.'</p>';
     ?>

   <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
   <header class="entry-header">
   <h1 class="entry-title">Submit Your List!</h1>
       </header>
        <div class="entry-content">
         <form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="" class="wpcf7-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <!-- post name -->
       <fieldset name="name">
       <input type="hidden" id="title" value="<?php echo date('F jS Y h:i:s A'); ?>" tabindex="5" name="title" />
      </fieldset>

  <div class="selects">
   <div class="selects1">
  <!-- list type -->
  <fieldset class="category">
    <?php erichamby_custom_taxonomy_dropdown( 'list_type', 'date', 'DESC', '10', 'list_type', '', '', 'Select List Type' ); ?>
  </fieldset>
   </div><div class="selects2">
  <!-- list state -->
  <fieldset class="category">
    <?php erichamby_custom_taxonomy_dropdown( 'list_state', 'date', 'DESC', '10', 'list_state', '', '', 'Select List State' ); ?>
  </fieldset>
  </div></div><div class="clear" ></div>

  <!-- post content -->
  <fieldset class="content space">
    <label for="description">Description and Notes:</label>
    <?php wp_editor("", 'description', array('media_buttons' => false, )); //change media_buttons to true to allow images/videos/music ?>
  </fieldset>

  <!-- post tags -->
  <fieldset class="tags space">
    <label for="post_tags">Additional Keywords (comma separated):</label>
    <input type="text" value="" tabindex="35" name="post_tags" id="post_tags" />
  </fieldset>

  <!-- submit -->
  <fieldset class="submit space">
    <input type="submit" value="Post Review" tabindex="40" id="submit" name="submit" />
  </fieldset>

  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />
  <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
</form>
  </div><!-- .entry-content --> 
</article><!-- #post -->
<?php
       }
        function erichamby_custom_taxonomy_dropdown( $taxonomy, $orderby = 'date', $order = 'DESC', $limit = '-1', $name, $show_option_all = null, $show_option_none = null,    $show_option_select = null ) {
   $args = array(
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => $order,
    'number' => $limit,
    'hide_empty' => 0,
      );
   $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
  $name = ( $name ) ? $name : $taxonomy;
   if ( $terms ) {
    printf( '<select name="%s" class="postform">', $name );
    if ( $show_option_select ) {
        printf( '<option>%s</option>', $show_option_select );
    }
    if ( $show_option_all ) {
        printf( '<option value="0">%s</option>', $show_option_all );
    }
    if ( $show_option_none ) {
        printf( '<option value="-1">%s</option>', $show_option_none );
    }
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        printf( '<option value="%s">%s</option>', $term->slug, $term->name       );
                       }
                                print( '</select>' );
                                  }
                }
               //EricHamby.Com
                   ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems with your code:

First You named your custom taxonomy `type` which is a [Reserved Term](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms)

Second You are trying to insert your taxonomy terms using `'post_category'` which wont get the job done. What you can do is either create a `'tax_input' => array('  in your new post array e.g:

```
$new_post = array(
    'post_title'   => stripslashes($title),
    'post_content' => stripslashes($description),
    'tags_input'   => stripslashes($tags),
    'post_status'  => 'publish', // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
    'post_type'    => 'user_lists', //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
    'tax_input'    => array(
        'type'  => $_POST['type'],
        'state' => $_POST['state'],
    )
);
```

or you can leave your code the way it is and use [**`wp_set_object_terms`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms)
after you get the new post ID e.g:

```
//SAVE THE POST
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
wp_set_object_terms( $pid, $_POST['type'], 'type' );
wp_set_object_terms( $pid, $_POST['state'], 'state' );
```

Update:

You need to make your register_taxonomy calls inside a hooked function so move then into your portfilio_register function and also give the action hooks priority e.g:

```
add_action('init', 'portfolio_register',100); 
function portfolio_register() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('User Lists', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('User List', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'list item'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New List'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit List Item'),
        'new_item' => __('New List Item'),
        'view_item' => __('View List Item'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Lists'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true, 
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/cutleries.png',
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'taxonomies' => array('post_tag', 'list_type', 'list_state'),
    'supports' => array('title',
        'editor',
        'author',
        'custom-fields',
        'comments')
          );

    register_post_type( 'user_lists' , $args ); 
    register_taxonomy("list_type", array("user_lists"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "List Types", "singular_label" => "List Type", "rewrite" => true, 'show_admin_column' => true,)); 
    register_taxonomy("list_state", array("user_lists"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "List State", "singular_label" => "List State", "rewrite" => true, 'show_admin_column' => true,));
}

add_action('init', 'catch_save_form',101);
```

As for your shortcode function you should return a value on a shortcode and not echo or print it out.

Comment: I have made the changes you suggest has you can see by the links and its still not posting. Did i do something wrong?

Comment: the reason It could the use of init hook, which can be before your post type of taxonomies are registered, try adding a late priority to it eg: `add_action('init', 'catch_save_form',1000);`

Comment: Hmm that did fix the tag issue, however the categories still aren't working. Never have i had this much issue using CPT.

Comment: Still have not got this working, and seems no one else knows either how to get custom tax to work with front end forms.

Comment: whats your current code? both form and processing

Comment: Ok code has been updated to what im trying to use now. Thanks

Comment: Anyone? surly someone can figure this out.

Comment: Once again no priority on your action hooks :(

Comment: i have no clue what that means

Comment: I updated my answer with an example and correction.